# Animaciones y transiciones no se activan al cambiar de pagina Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, web, ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Ruby on Rails, y cada vez que cambio de página, por ejemplo, ir de la página de inicio a la página de tienda, las animaciones del Navbar (el cual es el único contenido estático junto con el footer) se deshabilitan. La funcionalidad es la siguiente: cuando las pantallas son menores a 1024px de ancho, el menú original de deshabilita con un `display:none`, y en cambio muestro un menú tipo burger, el cual al dar click abre un responsive menú que abarca todo el alto y ancho de la pantalla y el cuál contiene todos los links. Como mencioné arriba, cuando cambio de página, este menú de deshabilita y nisiquiera abre, y tengo que refrescar el navegador para que vuelva a funcionar. ¿Qué puede ser lo que esté causando este mal funcionamiento?. No sé que parte del código poner en esta pregunta exactamente, así que si necesitan chequear algo en específico lo edito con gusto.

Adjunto el código a continuación:

/* Javascript file */

```javascript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let responsiveMenu = document.querySelector('.responsive-navbar');
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let burgerBtn = document.querySelector('.burger-menu');
  let responsiveLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.responsive-menu-links')
  burgerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    burgerBtn.classList.toggle('cross')
    responsiveMenu.classList.toggle('menu-open');
    body.classList.toggle('disable-scroll');
    responsiveLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.toggle('trigger-anim')
    })
  })
})
```

/* _navbar.html.erb partial */

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <%=link_to 'Inicio', root_path%>
    <a href="">ustedes</a>
    <a href="">contacto</a>
    <a href="">sobre mi</a>
    <%=link_to 'Tienda', store_path%>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-menu">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive-navbar">
  <div class="menu-background"></div>
  <div class="menu-links">
     <%=link_to 'Inicio', root_path, class: 'responsive-menu-links'%>
      <a href="" class="responsive-menu-links">ustedes</a>
      <a href="" class="responsive-menu-links">contacto</a>
      <a href="" class="responsive-menu-links">sobre mi</a>
      <%=link_to 'Tienda', store_path, class: 'responsive-menu-links'%>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

/* styles */

```css
.trigger-anim {
  animation: scaleIn .2s forwards;
}
.menu-open {
  width: 100vw !important;
  a {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}

.disable-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;

  .home-container {
    height: 100vh !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}

.cross {
  span {
    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      transform: rotate(40deg) translateY(20px);
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      transform: translateX(500px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3) {
      transform: rotate(-40deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.